# Subset columns from a data.frame creating many vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I have a `data.frame 11060x9(r x c)`.

I am trying to subset all these 9 columns to create 9 independent vectors called "ST[i]".
I know that I can get this typing

```
ST1 <- df[ ,1]
ST2 <- df[ ,2]
...
ST9 <- df[ ,9]
```

Although, I was wondering about a simplified way, like this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  ST[i] <- df[ , i]
  }
```

But the following message appeared:

> "Error in ST[i] <- df[, i] : object 'ST' not found"

How to fix it?

Comment: `ST = unname(as.list(DF[1:9]))`, referred to like `ST[[i]]`?

Comment: Yes, it is.
It appears that I needed to create a 'ST' object before, but I´m not sure, and I don´t know how.

Comment: Ok, fyi, you can initialize a list like `ST = list()` or `ST = vector(9, mode="list")`. You'll need to assign to it like `ST[[i]] <-` with two brackets.

Comment: Please, can you explain the reasoning why you need to split up your data.frame and create 9 independent objects? What can't be done if the data resides inside the data.frame?

Comment: You're right, Uwe. It didn't solve my problem. Now I need to run a comand with each vector, and it would be easier when they are all in a data.frame.
And I don´t know how to execute the same comand to each column ¬¬
I think I´ll need another question, in another post.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Here is how I would do this:

```
x <- data.frame(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
names <- as.character(rep(NA, ncol(x)))

for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  names[i] <- paste('ST', i, sep = "")
  assign(names[i], as.data.frame(x[,i], col.names = ""))
}
```

`assign()` is a very useful function when you want to create multiple vectors/data frames.

Comment: Great! It was enough!

Comment: I can't understand it too. I still don't have enough reputation to grow up yr answer.

Comment: @RafaelPedrollodePaes Do not worry about it. As long as you got your problem solved, everything else does not really matter.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter in this answer, but an explanation of what you have done and why it works would probably stop the down and delete votes...

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`: *The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use
the assign function.* (Greg Snow, R-help, July 2009)

Comment: @John3136 Thank you for your explanation. I am new to StackOverflow. I will try to explain every step in my answer in the future.

Comment: @Uwe You should put this line to your developer story